# Passing structs of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Suppose I have structs of pointers as such:

```
typedef struct person {
    char* name;
    struct person* neighbor;
} person;

typedef struct jail {
    struct person* first_inmate;
} jail;
```

I write the following to allocate these structs on the heap so that they persist outside local scope:

```
void create_person(const char* person_name, person** person_ptr2ptr) {
    if (!*person_ptr2ptr)
        *person_ptr2ptr = (person*) malloc(sizeof(person));
    (*person_ptr2ptr)->name = (char*)person_name;
    (*person_ptr2ptr)->neighbor = NULL;
}

jail* create_jail(void) {
    jail* _jail;
    _jail = (jail*) malloc(sizeof(jail));
    _jail->first_inmate = NULL;
    return _jail;
}
```

Why can't I 'insert' these `person`s into `jail` like this?

```
void imprison(jail* jail_ptr, person* person_ptr) {
    person* last_inmate = jail_ptr->first_inmate;
    while (last_inmate != NULL)
        last_inmate = last_inmate->neighbor;
    last_inmate = person_ptr;
}
```

I'll run into a segfault when I try to access `san_jose_jail->first_inmate` or any of the inmates' names:

```
int main(void) {
    person* alice_ptr = NULL;
    person* bob_ptr = NULL;
    create_person("Alice", &alice_ptr);
    create_person("Bob", &bob_ptr);

    jail* san_jose_jail = create_jail();
    imprison(san_jose_jail, alice_ptr);
    imprison(san_jose_jail, bob_ptr);
    // Why don't the pointers match?
    printf("Alice is at %p\n", (void*)alice_ptr);
    printf("First prisoner is at %p\n", (void*)san_jose_jail->first_inmate);
    // Segfaults after next line
    printf("Last prisoner's name is %s\n", san_jose_jail->first_inmate->neighbor->name);

    free(san_jose_jail);
    free(alice_ptr);
    free(bob_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to store a hash table whose values are pointers to structs, I'm able to insert/access the pointers themselves but the pointers dereference to garbage when I access them outside the scope of the insertion function. I think the above example abstracts away the problem and will help me understand how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this statement:

```
last_inmate = person_ptr;
```

You are modifying a local copy of the `neighbor` pointer, not the one within the struct is left untouch. The `imprison` method should be like this:

```
void imprison(jail* jail_ptr, person* person_ptr) {
    person** last_inmate = &jail_ptr->first_inmate;
    while (*last_inmate != NULL)
        last_inmate = &(*last_inmate)->neighbor;
    *last_inmate = person_ptr;
}
```

Comment: I get a compiler error on the line: `last_inmate = &last_inmate->neighbor;`, I don't think it type-checks: `pointerfun.c:30:35: error: request for member 'neighbor' in something not a structure or union.`Otherwise this seems to be the correct answer and explanation, I'll accept the corrected version - thanks!

Comment: I corrected it to `&((*last_inmate)->neighbor);` - works now! I think I understand the concept roughly now and can induce the rest from here, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

To add someone into jail, juste add it at begining of the list:

```
void imprison(jail* jail_ptr, person* person_ptr) {
    person_ptr->neighbor = jail_ptr->first_inmate;
    jail_ptr->first_inmate = person_ptr;
}
```